# Controller function not called from directive template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Directive template (items.html)

```
<li ng-repeat="item in itemCart">
    {{item.title}} <br>
    {{item.category}} &nbsp
    {{ formatCurrencyFunction({cost: item.price}) }}
</li>
```

This custom directive is used in Second.html

```
<h1>
    This is Second.
    {{header}}

</h1>
<hr>
<ul>  
  <items-list item-cart="items" format-currency-function="formatPrice(cost)"></items-list>
</ul>
```

The code for Controller is:

```
myApp.directive("itemsList", function(){
    return{
        templateUrl:"contents/Views/Directives/Items.html",
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            itemCart: "=",
            formatCurrencyFunction: "&"
        },
        restrict:"EACM" // E-Element A-Attribute C-Class M-Comments        
    }
})

myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $log, $http, $routeParams) {
     $scope.formatPrice = function(price){        
        return "₹ "+parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);
    };
    $scope.header = 'Second ' + ($routeParams.num || "");
    $scope.testSecond = "Second";
    $http.get("/items")
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;        
    });  

}]);
```

The function formatPrice is not called from the directive Items.html

What has to be corrected in my code to get it working?

Comment: Any reason that the formatPrice function needs to exist in the controller? Would you be able to move it to the directive instead?

Comment: Hi Tah Tatsumoto.. I was learning how to get the Application working by passing the scope from the parent to the child Directive.. Yes it would work the way u are suggesting to use the function.. but i need to understand why this approach is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the directive's link function, you'll want to call the method like so:

```
scope.someFn({arg: someValue});

myApp.directive("itemsList", function(){
return{
    templateUrl:"contents/Views/Directives/Items.html",
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        itemCart: "=",
        formatCurrencyFunction: "&formatCurrencyFunction"
    },
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.formatPrice({arg: 35}); //scope.someFn({arg: 35});
    },
    restrict:"EACM" // E-Element A-Attribute C-Class M-Comments        
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by using ng-repeat in the Second.html page instead of the directive.

Directive template (items.html)

```
<li>
    {{item.title}} <br>
    {{item.category}} &nbsp
    {{ formatCurrencyFunction({cost: item.price}) }}
</li>
```

This custom directive is used in Second.html

```
<h1>
    This is Second.
    {{header}}

</h1>
<hr>
<ul>  
  <items-list item="item" format-currency-function="formatPrice(cost)" ng-repeat="item in items"></items-list>
</ul>
```

Code in JS file

```
myApp.directive("itemsList", function(){
    return{
        templateUrl:"contents/Views/Directives/Items.html",
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            item: "=",
            formatCurrencyFunction: "&"
        },
        restrict:"EACM" // E-Element A-Attribute C-Class M-Comments        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the directive's link function, you need to call the method by applying some event to that attribute

Answer (score 0):

Controller function 'formatCurrencyFunction()' can't be called by just placing it in an expression.

To use the function you need to call it based on an even, in your case ng-init will work.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in itemCart" ng-init="formatCurrencyFunction({cost: item.price})">
{{item.title}} <br>
{{item.category}}
</li>
```